# How can I refer or ping two users in a comment?

Tags: support

I know that we cannot use two @usernames in a single comment. I just recently saw [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619152/how-to-create-rest-urls-without-verbs#comment1486653_1619207) where it has two @usernames allowed. How did SO allowed this comment?

And, Do I need to enter the same comment twice to notify each user individually?

Or If I use back-ticks `@username` the user would still be notified?

Comment: @RobertLongson In some situations, we might need to convey both users the same opinion. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-use-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings-in-comments/2615#comment9529_2615

Answer (score 4):

You cannot, and the comment you linked did not. It just @mentioned 2 users, but only one was pinged. The system will not permit you to ping more then one user in a comment.

Comment: Yes, I know I cannot. My question was how SO allowed two @user in a comment. Is that comment too old before that policy?

Comment: @Lucky doesn't. You can submit it past the error with some html fiddling

Comment: @lucky or using the reduced markdown > _@Magisch_

Comment: ^And actually 2 were pinged here :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, 2 users can be pinged at max. Not more than that. Whether or not you mention the owner of the post is always notified and you are allowed to ping one more user with `@user`. What if you need to ping more than one user excluding the post owner?

Comment: @Lucky Write an extra comment for each. There's no other way currently.

Comment: @Lucky Shouldn't happen often, but if it does, just post another comment on the same post.

Comment: Yeah, it was allowed there because ~7 years ago. But only one person got the ping, even way back then. What πάντα ῥεῖ is talking about is that Magisch *always* gets pinged, because he's the author of the post. You do not need to use the at-sign notation for the author (and the comment system will sometimes provide a warning if you try to do so, I believe). So you can at-reply another user who is participating in the comments, and they will get notified along with the author of the post, effectively notifying two people. This two-people backdoor has nothing to do with the at-reply system. @luck

Comment: @Cody _"(and the comment system will sometimes provide a warning if you try to do so, I believe)"_ It gets through as soon there were other users involved. Otherwise the pinged name will be simply removed from the comment (without warning) AFAIK.